# Way to disable top panel on second monitor? or at least hide it properly

Tags: unity, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

when im running a video in fullscreen in vlc on my second monitor or any other video player the top panel bar appears as soon as i give focus to an application on my main monitor. Have never seen this behavior on other desktop environtments. Is it a bug? I can't find any way to fix this.

Bug/missing feature since 2011. Is this ever gonna get looked into? 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/853865

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? This has been fixed long ago.

Comment: 15.04 fully updated and fresh install from yesterday.

Comment: I did not test it on 15.04 because I do not have a second screen there. But in 14.04 it has been fixed. Maybe it is a regression in unity again. If you use VLC, clicking on the window title ans selecting "always on top" is a workaround.

Comment: I converted it to a question, because it seems to affect many people in 15.04.

Comment: I suggest reporting it as a separate bug in 15.04. There will be a chance to get it fixed again.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for clearing that up! will definently make a bug report then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 15.04.

A workaround for VLC is to right-click the window title and select "Always on top".

Comment: This can be controlled from command-line as well: `wmctrl -r "VLC media player" -b add,fullscreen,above` (tested with Ubuntu 16.04). Allows me to put the top-bar below the VLC player fullscreen window, looks good even if VLC is not active on the second display.